# Java APNS Push notificaton from java to iOS app using FCM token?

Tags: java, ios, swift, swift3

I want to send push notification from java web application to iOS app. It shows error .. I have used bellow code to send notification from java server to iOS app.

```
import com.notnoop.apns.*;
public class PushNotifications {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      PushNotifications pushNotifications = new PushNotifications();
      pushNotifications.sendNotificaton();
    } 

void sendNotificaton() {

    ApnsService service
            = APNS.newService()
                    .withCert(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Certificates.p12"), "123456")
                    .withSandboxDestination() 
                    .build();

    String payload
            = APNS.newPayload()
                    .alertBody("My Message")
                    .badge(1)
                    .sound("default")
                    .build();

  //Token
    String deviceToken = "BD00825B7FDA300705C2EFDE0821B94815F9D76CCFE54BF36CF23E8EAAC949EC";

    //log.warn("Sending push notification...");
    service.push(deviceToken, payload);
  } 

}
```

Note: My Certificates.p12 paste to netbeans  default source package directory.
My Error show..

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.jackson.type.JavaType.isMapLikeType()Z
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BasicSerializerFactory.buildContainerSerializer(BasicSerializerFactory.java:416)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.createSerializer(BeanSerializerFactory.java:268)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._createUntypedSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:782)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._createAndCacheUntypedSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:735)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.findValueSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:344)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.findTypedValueSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:420)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:601)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:256)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:2575)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:2097)
at com.notnoop.apns.PayloadBuilder.build(PayloadBuilder.java:365)
at fcm.PushNotifications.sendNotificaton(PushNotifications.java:34)
at fcm.PushNotifications.main(PushNotifications.java:17)
/Users/Enamul/Library/Caches/NetBeans/8.2/executor-snippets/run.xml:53:     Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

With advance thanks..Please help me..

Comment: your Jackson package path is "org.codehaus" , which signals me that this is Jackson 1... so it might be that you have the wrong Jackson version .. at the end I would guess you have Jackson 1.9.x and you need 2.x...

Comment: yes i have used jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.31

Comment: does it work now ?

Comment: i have used jackjon-cor- 2.0.0 it shows errorat com.notnoop.apns.PayloadBuilder.<clinit>(PayloadBuilder.java:47)
 at com.notnoop.apns.APNS.newPayload(APNS.java:48)
 at fcm.PushNotifications.sendNotificaton(PushNotifications.java:28)
 at fcm.PushNotifications.main(PushNotifications.java:17)

Comment: hello sir it doesn't work.. when i use jackson version above 2

Comment: Hello sir, I have used apns-0.2.3.jar